# Mozilla Django OpenID Logout does not revoke token

Tags: django, openid-connect, okta

I've been working to integrate a django app with mozilla-django-oidc and I can't seem to figure out how to log out of the thing correctly.
On my main page I have

```
<form action="{% url 'oidc_logout' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="logout">
```

which provides the logout assuming a user is logged in. Logging in seems to work well enough.
In my settings I'm providing the logout configurations

```
OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT = cfgs.get("LOGOUT_ENDPOINT")
OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_METHOD = "test_app_2.openid.logout"    
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('post-logout')
POST_LOGOUT_URL = cfgs.get("LOGOUT_REDIRECT")
```

Which are my okta oidc logout endpoint, the method that I wrote to create the correct logout url and logout redirect. I created a POST_LOGOUT_URL variable so I can access the post-logout url elsewhere.

openid.logout looks like this

```
def logout(request):
    id_token = str(request.COOKIES['csrftoken'])

    logout_request = \
        f'{settings.OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT}?id_token_hint={id_token}' \
        f'&post_logout_redirect_uri={settings.POST_LOGOUT_URL}'    

return logout_request
```

Which is the correct logout url configuration for oidc. I've tested all this through a flask app and it all works just fine. Why don't I just use flask? It's a long story. I'd rather use Django...

In my views.py I have

```
class LogoutView(OIDCLogoutView):      
    def get(self, request):
        return self.post(request)
```

Which I confess to have grabbed from another post and I'm not entirely sure how it works with my urls which are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('post_logout/', views.post_logout, name='post-logout'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('main_page/', views.main_page, name='main-page'),
]
```

So I'm not entirely sure how that works in context with **OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_METHOD**

So this (incorrectly) seems to work. It jumps right to my post_logout page but as far as I can tell it never executes the redirect to the actual okta logout url. And sure enough nothing is actually logged out. My app session seems to think I'm logged out as I can go back to my main page and it says I am logged out. However if I click log in I don't have to go through the okta authentication. It's still retaining the okta session.

So my question is how to actually get it to follow the flow of the **OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_METHOD**. I know I have this configured incorrectly but there's very little instructional help on the subject through their docs that I have been able to follow.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I sorted it out.
Logout is called from the imported urls so I don't need to specify a different logout url. I removed that and it still didn't work.

However **OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_METHOD** is incorrect. It needed to be **OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_URL_METHOD**

That set everything working.

Whoops...